# Excel Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, worksheet

I have a spreadsheet that will be completed by various staff which has numerous columns and rows and the cells will all have numbers in. I then need to somehow amalgamate the data in such a way that I can filter on an individual and it will show their data only. Problem is I will have over 30 separate worksheets. Any ideas please. I cannot pivot the master template as the rows have too many titles.

Comment: A word of advice when it comes to creating a spreadsheet template that multiple users will fill in: your users are going to do the unexpected and it's going to make compilation hell. I had this issue some years ago with just 4 users. They were supposed to put a value of 1-4 in each cell, but they also decided to put comments into many of these cells among other things.

Comment: Thanks @Kyrubas I have thought of that and will be putting drop lists only so they will not be able to add anything else in the cells

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Master sheet which references to the other sheets. So for example, you could link the cells of the Master sheet to the ones of the other sheets so that when you populate the other sheets you will have all the data automatically in the Master sheet.

Otherwise, create a VBA code to copy paste the content of the workbooks into the Master sheet.

Comment: Thanks @madrac. The only thing is I want to be able to filter in the master sheet for any one individual but cannot think how to do that.